Shape in .background modifier auto apply into sheets?
I have the following simplified view:
@State private var showSheet = false
var body: some View {
    Text("Test button")
        .padding(50)
        .onTapGesture {
            showSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text("Sheet")
                .padding(50)
                .background(.teal)
        }
        .background(.orange, in: .rect(cornerRadius: 20))
}

If I apply .background() after .sheet() like the above code, the Text inside the sheet got the corner radius in the background colour as well, as shown in the screenshot.

If I reverse the order of .background() and .sheet(), the background colour of the Text inside the sheet shows no corner radius, which is what I expected.

I understand the order of modifiers matter in SwiftUI. But should the background shape auto apply into the attached sheet?
As a test, I've tried to remove .background(.teal) inside the sheet view. In this case, the Text inside the sheet view didn't inherit any orange background.
So, to summarise, if I apply a .background() after a .sheet(), any element inside the sheet view will inherit the background "shape", but not the background colour. Is this an expected behaviour or a bug?

Edit:
Tested in a new project, using just the above mentioned code, with Xcode 16.0 in iPhone 16 Pro simulator (iOS 18.0)


Edit 2:
Submitted feedback FB15477012

This looks like a bug to me.

What version of iOS are you using? It sounds like a bug that has been resolved - I just tested this with a quick min iOS 17 app and deployed to iPhone 16 simulator with multiple variations of your example and each one came up with a square edged shape in the sheet, no rounded corners.

I am not getting rounded corners in the sheet Text either. Maybe share the entire struct to see what the rest looks like?

@AndreiG. Thanks for the test! I have just created a new project, adding exactly the codes above, still having the same rounded rectangle in the sheet. I'm using Xcode 16 with iPhone 16 Pro simulator (iOS18.0). Please see my edit.

@okat Thanks! Please see my comment and edit above.

Indeed, I do see the same when running in the simulator. I had previously tried in XCode Preview and device preview, where the sheet box doesn't have rounded corners. So looks like a simulator bug?

@AndreiG. Tried on a real device iPhone 15 (iOS17.6.1), same rounded corners.  Also same results in iPad Swift Playgrounds.

After some further testing I've confirmed that this rounded corner effect is happening when the Text exists at the very top level of the view.
As soon as you embed it in any kind of container - e.g. VStack, Group, even NavigationStack - it renders with square edges as you expected.
Note that if you put it as-is (no container) within a child view and call that directly from ContentView you will still get rounded corners.
Not sure if that rounding behavior is a bug or actually "expected" behavior for modifiers applied on the top level of a view though sorry!

@okat Wow thanks for that! Further to your test, I’ve found that with the Text being embedded inside a container, if you apply the rounded background to the container, the elements inside Sheet will get rounded background as well. I’ll file a feedback to Apple to see. Thanks everyone for your help!
